# Why does the following compile if the non-POD constant isn't explicitly defined?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was under the impression that all `const` members had to be explicitly initialized by the constructor once, but after testing it seems as if only POD types have to be initialized. The following compiles regardless of whether `b` is mentioned in the constructor or not:

```
#include <string>

struct A {
    const int a;
    const std::string b;

    A() : a{} {}
};
```

Example: http://cpp.sh/36my2

Comment: Because otherwise POD members are very likely to contain garbage (be uninitialized). In this way you ensure that any user-defined type will be initialized.

Comment: `std::string` has a default constructor that initializes it, but POD types don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by C++14 [dcl.init]/7:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

Providing no initializer for an object, in this context, is "calling for default initialization".  "User-provided default constructor" means that there is a constructor defined that can be called with zero arguments, and that constructor was not set to `=default;`.

The `std::string` class does in fact have a user-provided default constructor.
So this rule prevents you from omitting `a{}`, but it does not force you to provide any initializer for `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a user supplied default constructor, so default constructing `b` will give it a "meaningful" value (it will be an empty string). The constructor can therefore default initialize it implicitly.

`int` however is a trivially constructible type. Its default constructor does absolutely nothing, so the content of `a` is indeterminate unless explicitly initialized in the member initializer list. List initializing (using braces `{}`) `a` will preform value initialization on it, and will end up giving it the well defined value of 0.

The member variables must be initialized with a meaningful value, because the program cannot change them afterwards. That's the rationale behind demanding an initializer.